# Why Past Perfect in this example?

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, past-simple

The example below is from a grammar guide

> This glass is cracked. ~ So it is. I **hadn't** noticed.

Why not *"I **haven't** noticed"*? - *Present Perfect*, as it is something he hasn't noticed until the moment the other one said *"It is cracked"*.

Or that can be just *"I didn't notice"* - *Simple Past*.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: By the time of the remark, the speaker has finally noticed. He hadn't noticed until now, but now he has, because you pointed it out.

Comment: @Raj33 Beware, the answer below which you commented on is **incorrect**. Chaim's comment above is spot on.

Answer (score -1):

Sentences using Past perfect should end with a reference to another point of time in the past. For example, *I hadn't noticed it earlier or before*. Then it would have been correct.

Not using the Present perfect or Simple present tense may indicate that the writer wants to relate his *noticing the glass cracked* to a past time.

Nonetheless, I would suppose that the sentence is incorrect or incomplete. Where did u read it?

Comment: In a grammar guide. But that's for a different subject.

Comment: I agree with the Past Perfect explanation. But can you explain why it is wrong to use with Present Perfect and Simple Past?

Comment: I would hesitate to question the authenticity of the Grammar guide but, nonetheless I would say that a reference to a past event is must when using past perfect.

Comment: "I haven't noticed it yet" & "Oh sorry, I didn't notice that"???

Comment: Use of Past perfect is simply to denote that the "noticing of the cracked glass" has been in the past, as in: " I hadn't noticed the crack earlier." Use of  "haven't" would bring the scenario to the present, which the author didin't imply to. Which tense is to be used is what forms the structure of the paragraph (or sentence).

Comment: What about using Simple Past here?

Comment: Simple past can be taken into consideration, but then it would depict that the author didn't notice it earlier, and now he is narrating this scene in the Present. The point is still there; he wants to state the scenario of noticing as  of something of the Past.

Comment: My pleasure.:) Hope I made myself clear enough.

Comment: -1, this answer is incorrect. The original sentence is **not** wrong, and an _explicit_ reference to a past event is **not** required for the past perfect.